# Property of Exponential.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function

Can anyone please explain how $$\exp[y/\alpha]=\exp[y-\log\alpha]$$
?

I tried as :

$$\exp[y/\alpha]=\exp(y/\exp[\log\alpha])=?$$

I think $$\exp(y)\exp[-\log\alpha],$$ can be written as $$\exp[y-\log\alpha].$$

But not $$\exp(y/\exp[\log\alpha]),$$ can be written as $$\exp[y-\log\alpha].$$

Answer (score 1):

The left-hand side should read $\exp(y)/a$
Can you take it from there?
$$\exp(y)/a=\exp(y)/\exp(\log a)=\exp(y-\log a)$$
On the other hand, 
$$\exp(6/3)=\exp(2)=e^2=7.389\\
\exp(6)/3=(e^6)/3=403.429/3=134.476$$

Comment: Is $\exp(y/a)=(1/a)\exp(y)$?

Comment: No, $exp(y/a)=\sqrt[a]{\exp(y)}$ is quite different.

Comment: Could you please add a little more explanation to your answer ?